# If $a^n$ is equivalent to $b^n$ (mod c) then does this imply a is equivalent to b (mod c)?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations

I see the property that a equivalent to b (mod c) implies a^n is equivalent to b^n (mod c) for a non-negative integer n, but cannot figure out if it works in the other direction.  A link to the property or proof, or a counterexample would be appreciated.

I am not new to math but am new to number theory.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: For every integer $a$ for which $a\not\equiv0\pmod p$, we have $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$. Thus loads of counterexamples to your conjecture.

Comment: $4^n\equiv12^n\bmod16$ for all $n\ge2$, but $4\not\equiv12\bmod16$.

Comment: @Lubin, I have seen that property but don't understand it.  May I have an explanation of it?

Comment: Well, first of all, you must look at some examples. Look at $p=3$ and $a=2\not\equiv1\pmod3$. Look at $p=5$ and $a=2,3,4\not\equiv1\pmod5$. Look at $p=7$ and $a=2,3,4,5,6\not\equiv1\pmod7$. Then look modulo $7$ again, and write out all the powers of $3$, as congruence classes, and see that all are run through (except $0$ of course). Then you have to learn enough group theory to see that in any multiplicative group of order $n$ (in our case, $n=p-1$), every element’s $n$-th power is $1$. That will help your understanding.

Answer (score 2):

No. For example 
$2^4\equiv 1^4 \pmod 5$,but $2\not\equiv 1 \pmod 5$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$1^2 \equiv (-1)^2 \pmod{ c}$$

That is $$1^2 \equiv (c-1)^2 \pmod{ c}$$

However $1 \not \equiv c-1 \pmod{c} $ for any $c\ge3$.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not sure how to read all of your statements.  How do you bring in (c-1)^2?

Comment: We have $c-1 \equiv -1 \pmod{c}$ hence $(c-1)(c-1) \equiv (-1)(c-1) \equiv (-1)(-1) \pmod{c}$.